# Not able to effectively remove strings before ‘v’ or deleting strings v and after

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I am removing strings before ‘v’ or deleting strings v and after

```
My data looks like:
Potato onions v carrot pickles
Chocolate cake v orange cake
Chicken breasts v Vegan Quinoa
Vienna sauvsage v velovute vegetvable
Etc,,
```

My desired output is:

```
Potato onions 
Chocolate cake 
Chicken breasts 
Vienna sauvsage
```

The common feature is they have a ‘v’
I have tried something like

```
data['result'] = data['result'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('+-').rstrip('aAbBcC'))
```

This seems to be useful for static data, and removing specific parts of a string where as my data is dynamic and constantly being updated and changed.  I am wanting to make it look like:
`Vienna sauvsage v velovute vegetvable`  to `Vienna sauvsage`
The below tends to work unrealiably and with a later trim.

```
df['result'] = df.result.str.extract('((?=).* v(=?))', expand=True).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the spaces either side are fixed then you could use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas.Series.str.split):

```
In[90]:
df['result'] = df['str'].str.split(' v ').str[0]
df

Out[90]: 
                                     str           result
0         Potato onions v carrot pickles    Potato onions
1           Chocolate cake v orange cake   Chocolate cake
2         Chicken breasts v Vegan Quinoa  Chicken breasts
3  Vienna sauvsage v velovute vegetvable  Vienna sauvsage
```

So this splits the string on `' v '` and returns the first entry in the split

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
In [6]: df['result'] = df.result.str.split('\s+v\s+').str[0]

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
            result
0    Potato onions
1   Chocolate cake
2  Chicken breasts
3  Vienna sauvsage
```